# how can I retrieve nearest restaurant detail using latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am android developer and I want to retrieve nearest restaurant detail based on user entered latitude and longitude detail.

Answer (score -1):

Already been answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)** (distance between latitude and longitude coordinates).
To quote:

> This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) might be helpful to
>   you.
>
> Excerpt:
>
> > This script calculates great-circle
> >     distances between the two points –
> >     that is, the shortest distance over
> >     the earth’s surface – using the
> >     ‘Haversine’ formula.
> >
> > Javascript:
> >
> > ```
> > var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
> > var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
> > var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
> > var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
> >         Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
> >         Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
> > var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),
> > ```
> >
> > Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
> >         var d = R * c; // Distance in km
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points):
>   http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I don't even remember writing this. What was I thinking?